# torch - LookupTable and gradient update

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, torch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a neural network with multiple layers. I am trying to understand if what I have done is correct and if not, how do I debug this. The way I do it is, I define my neural network in the following manner (I initialise the lookuptable layer with some prior learned embeddings):

```
lookupTableLayer = nn.LookupTable(vector:size()[1], d)
for i=1,vector:size()[1] do
  lookupTableLayer.weight[i] = vector[i]
end
mlp=nn.Sequential();
mlp:add(lookupTableLayer)
mlp:add(nn.TemporalConvolution(d,H,K,dw))
mlp:add(nn.Tanh())
mlp:add(nn.Max(1))
mlp:add(nn.Tanh())
mlp:add(nn.Linear(H,d))
```

Now, to train the network, I loop through every training example and for every example I call gradUpdate() which has this code (this is straight from the examples):

```
function gradUpdate(mlp, x, indexY, learningRate)
  local pred = mlp:forward(x)
  local gradCriterion = findGrad(pred, indexY)
  mlp:zeroGradParameters()
  mlp:backward(x, gradCriterion)
  mlp:updateParameters(learningRate)
end
```

The findGrad function is just an implementation of WARP Loss which returns the gradient wrt output. I am wondering if this is all I need? I assume this will backpropagate and update the parameters of all the layers. To check this, I trained this network and saved the model. Then I loaded the model and did:

```
{load saved mlp after training}
lookuptable = mlp:findModules('nn.LookupTable')[1]
```

Now, I checked vector[1] and lookuptable.weight[1] and they were the same. I can't understand why did the weights in the lookup table layer not get updated? What am I missing here?

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: was vector[1] shown during training at all? LookupTable does sparse gradient updates on the embeddings indexed during the mini-batch, compare the norms of the weights of the whole LookupTable before and after (and see if they are exact or slightly different)

Comment: pretty sure vector[1] was an input in one of the training examples as it's the most frequent word in the corpus, however I'll confirm. I also checked on a couple other random indexes and they seemed to be the same. I'll check the norm and post here. Overall, does the implementation look fine? I am not sure if I am doing everything right in the gradUpdate() function

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with the choice of regularisation parameter as specified in the WSABIE paper. Need to take care of that. Thanks!